# graphqljs - how to get file name and line of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am using graphqljs along with `express-graphql`. Whenever I get error I'll get something vague like `"Expected type Int!, found \"1\"` with an unhelpful location property:

```
"locations": [
    {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 42
    }
],
```

What can I do to get the file name and its line?

Error below:

```
"{
    "errors": [
        {
            "json": "{\"message\":\"Expected type Int!, found \\\"1\\\".\",\"locations\":[{\"line\":3,\"column\":42}]}",
            "message": "Expected type Int!, found \"1\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 42
                }
            ],
            "stack": [
                "GraphQLError: Expected type Int!, found \"1\".",
                "    at isValidScalar (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/ValuesOfCorrectType.js:164:27)",
                "    at Object.StringValue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/ValuesOfCorrectType.js:128:14)",
                "    at Object.enter (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:333:29)",
                "    at Object.enter (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:384:25)",
                "    at visit (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:251:26)",
                "    at validate (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
                "    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whylookforit-server/node_modules/express-graphql/dist/index.js:154:52",
                "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)"
            ]
        }
    ]
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

All your graphql code gets bundled into one big schema and only after it is done the coge gets run. If there is an error when the schema gets run, the code doesn’t have a reference to the file it initially got defined in anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `formatError`, for execution errors you can access the `path` property of the error to at least identify which resolver blew up. In these cases, the stack will also usually show the file where the error occurred.

The error you are seeing here is a validation error that's getting thrown because the document you're sending is not valid. Since it's not an execution error, there's nothing you need to fix server-side. Client side, you need to fix your query. The `locations` property tells us the error is on the 3rd line of your document at the 42nd character of that line. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to identify the specific node from the error alone.

Comment: that's exactly what I have already, and that's what is being output from my question.

Comment: @A.Lau Sorry, totally misread the question. Please see the updated answer.